# Sitecore XMCloud custom language

Tags: xm-cloud

During Sitecore MVC time, we can customize the LanguageResolver to map custom language to the supported language. For example, whenever I type in `/sc` my custom resolver can map `sc` to `zh-CN`.

As we are moving to Sitecore XM Cloud, our frontend NextJS is making graphQL request to get the content. I tried using the old way to map `sc` to `zh-CN` but not working because the old way is to detect the language in the URL path and querystring (`sc_lang`).

Below is the graphQL which I'm going to use, would like to know which pipeline should I customize in order to map `sc` language to `zh-CN` in Sitecore.

```
query {
  # path can be an item tree path or GUID-based id
  item(
      path: "/sitecore/content/Home", 
      language: "sc"
      ) {
    rendered
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

xmCloud has support for creating custom languages, it does not depend on the standard predefined cultures of .net framework anymore.
Please check this blog:
https://www.ashournia.com/new-xmcloud-language-localizations/

As I understand, you want to create a non-standard culture like: en-XX, it should not be an issue using xmcloud and is supported out of the box.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/users/xm-cloud/add-a-new-language-to-system-settings.html

Comment: I wanted to map /sc to /zh-CN, tried your recommendation, still not working..